# Search in ListView (with Data from Firebase) in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, listview, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to implement a search function into my app. Right now I got a ListView, which displays the data I get from a Firebase Database as a Stream. Do you have any Ideas how to search this List?

Here is my code for the ListView:

```
import "package:rate_my_food_1/models/imbiss.dart";
import "package:provider/provider.dart";
import "package:rate_my_food_1/widgets/imbiss_tile.dart";

class ImbissList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImbissListState createState() => _ImbissListState();
}

class _ImbissListState extends State<ImbissList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final imbiss = Provider.of<List<Imbiss>>(context);


    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Suchen...", hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: imbiss.length ?? 0,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return ImbissTile(imbiss: imbiss[index]);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

And here is how I implemented the ListView in my homescreen of the App:

```
import 'package:rate_my_food_1/models/imbiss.dart';
import "package:rate_my_food_1/services/database.dart";
import "package:provider/provider.dart";
import "package:rate_my_food_1/widgets/imbiss_list.dart";




class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamProvider<List<Imbiss>>.value(
        value: DatabaseService().imbisses,
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
          //Add Button
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/add");
            },
            child: Icon (Icons.add),
            backgroundColor: Colors.cyanAccent,
          ),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SafeArea(child: SizedBox(height: 10.0,)),
              //Imbissliste
              Expanded(child: ImbissList()),
            ],
          )
        )
    );
  }
}
```

I was thinking about making a second List in which I can Filter only for objects which contain what I'm writing into the TextField, but I have no clue how to do that properly.
Do you have any Ideas on how to search in this ListView?

If you need any more code from my Project, please let me know.
Thanks for all answers!
Yoqora

EDIT:
This is my Code atm, with the problem that it doesn't show the ListView and TextField when I start the app:

```
import "package:rate_my_food_1/models/imbiss.dart";
import "package:provider/provider.dart";
import "package:rate_my_food_1/widgets/imbiss_tile.dart";

class ImbissList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImbissListState createState() => _ImbissListState();
}

class _ImbissListState extends State<ImbissList> {

  List<Imbiss> imbiss = [];
  List<Imbiss> filteredImbiss = [];

  @override
  initState() {
    imbiss = Provider.of<List<Imbiss>>(context);
    filteredImbiss = imbiss;

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Suchen...", hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
               filteredImbiss = imbiss.where((imbiss) => imbiss.name.contains(value)).toList();
             });
            },
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 10,),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: filteredImbiss.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
              return ImbissTile(imbiss: filteredImbiss[index]);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}`
```

Comment: Hey! Do you only want to filter in the list that you've already loaded? Or do you want to dynamically query firestore?

Comment: Dynamically query firestore sounds ideal, but I would be happy with both solutions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can filter the retrieved data using a key in state. This key kan be updated using the `onChanged(String)` method from the `TextField` widget. We simply filter the list on every build, please see the example below:

```dart
class ImbissList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ImbissListState createState() => _ImbissListState();
}

class _ImbissListState extends State<ImbissList> {
  // The search key to filter the imbisses.
  String key = '';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var imbisses = Provider.of<List<Imbiss>>(context);

    // Filter the imbisses using the key.
    imbisses = imbisses.where((imbiss) {
      return imbiss.name.contains(key);
    }).toList();

    return Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Suchen...",
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            onChanged: (value) {
              // Update the key when the value changes.
              setState(() => key = value);
            },
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 10,
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: imbisses.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ImbissTile(imbiss: imbisses[index]);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your fast answer. But for some reason when I start the app now, all I get is a grey screen. It also doesn't show the TextField.. the only thing that is there, is the floatingActionButton. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. When I try to implement the widget above it works just fine. Does Flutter throw any errors?

Comment: I don't get any errors. After some trial and error I found out that when I initialize the lists not in the InitState but directly in the Build Widget with "imbiss = Provider.of<List<Imbiss>>(context);
    filteredImbiss = imbiss;" it works as before and shows me the List and the TextField but nothing happens when I type something in..

Comment: That's correct. That way, the lists will be initialised on every build (so when the textField updates), and therefore nothing will change. Maybe the only option is to pass the `Imbisses` as a parameter to the `ImbissList` widget?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? (If you have the time)

Comment: After some trial and error I finally managed to get it working. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, this solution works perfectly fine! Thank you so much for your time and effort to help me out :)

Comment: No problem! An accepted answer would be awesome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Hey i tried the same thing but i'm getting a blank screen, if possible can you please share the source code.

Edit: I figured out where i was going wrong. Thank you so much for the solution this was really helpful